# javascript button key press is fired n times in n'th click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a game where there is a start button. After this button is pressed the game starts. The game has multiple keyboard key press events. The problem is when start button is pressed n'th time and the game starts running n'th time, for every keyboard key press event the program makes n time key press. Below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.start_game').click( function(){

        $(document).keydown(function(e){ // left button
            if (e.keyCode == 37 && game_over_flag == 0) 
            { 
                if(a!=0)    
                {
                    remove_obj(a,b);
                    a=a-1;
                    placement(a,b); 

                    check_collision(a,b);
                }
            }
        });

   });

});
```

So when the start game is pressed second time and then the arrow button is pressed once, it takes two clicks. For third start game button click, every single key stroke works three times, where for single click, i need single time execution .Plz help.

Comment: We need to see more code to determine why.

Comment: try to use `.one` instead `.keydown` ... http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: u mean the functions ?

Comment: ... wait, maybe i don't understand your problem (my english suck a little bit :D ) ... you need to press "start button" n times or only one times?

Comment: DO NOT BIND the event inside another event!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each game try something like

```
$(document).unbind('keydown');
```

You are binding a new event handler every time the user clicks.

Comment: Or set the keydown handler outside of the click handler

Comment: It seems like he doesn't want the keydown to be active until the user presses 'start game'.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you click the button, it adds a new event handler. So you would need to unbind it.

```
$('.start_game').click( function () {

    $(document).off("keydown.game").on("keydown.game", function (e) {
    ...
```

Or even better not bind inside the click event, use a flag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var isActive = false;
    $('.start_game').click( function(){
        isActive = true
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(e){ // left button
        if (!isActive) {
            return;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 37 && game_over_flag == 0) 
        ...
```